# why facedetection not happening in Portrait mode in Android , using javaCV cvHaarDetectObjects method

Tags: android, javacv

I tried to modify the `FacePreview.java` sample provided for Android and since that code always open your camera in landscape mode, I added orientation logic in `Preview.java`, once we opens the camera:

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

When I ran the program I found always the Object detection i.e. `cvHaarDetectObjects` only works if the phone is in landscape mode, in other modes mainly in portrait, it's not at all detecting any face.
What is the reason behind this?

```
faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(
    grayImage,
    classifier,
    storage,
    1.1,
    3,
    CV_HAAR_FEATURE_MAX
      | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE 
      | CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
      | CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
      | CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);
```

`faces.total` always returns `0` when the phone is in portrait mode or orientation is different that landscape.

I tried modifying places but didn't find the expected.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in OpenCV/JavaCV Haar classifier (xml file) was trained using landscape images. You can rotate your Mat object before face detection:

```
public static opencv_core.Mat rotate(opencv_core.Mat src, int angle) {
    opencv_core.IplImage iplSrc = src.asIplImage();
    opencv_core.IplImage iplRes = opencv_core.IplImage.create(
        iplSrc.height(),
        iplSrc.width(),
        iplSrc.depth(),
        iplSrc.nChannels()
    );
    cvTranspose(iplSrc, iplRes);
    cvFlip(iplRes, iplRes, angle);
    return new opencv_core.Mat(iplRes);
```

So if you are loading your Mat from some image file, you can do something like that:

```
opencv_core.Mat mat = imread(imagePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
int orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
try {
     ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
     orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
switch (orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
       mat = MatUtils.rotate(mat, 90);
       break;
}
```